# Undefined variable: foods

Tags: laravel

hi guys am in need of assistance , i know this seems to be an easy one but am a bit confused , i have a foreach loop in my main.blade.php file, which shows foods from my database it works fine but when its clicked it meant to lead to the individual post and thats where i get the error
**Undefined variable: foods**

**heres my foreach loop in main.blade.php file**

```
@foreach($foods as $food)  
    <li class="item">
        <a href="{{ route('Foods.show', $food->id) }}">
            <img src="{{ Storage::disk('local')->url('food_images/'.$food->image ) }}" class="img-responsive w-25 p-3" alt="Food" >
            <div class="menu-desc text-center">
                <span>
                    <h3> {{ $food->title }}</h3>
                    {{ $food->body }}
                </span>
            </div>
        </a>     
        <h2 class="white"> #{{ $food->price }}</h2>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**heres my main.blade.php controller**

```
public function LoadHome()
{          
    $foods = Food::all();
    $foods = Food::orderBy('created_at','desc')->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(12)
        ->get();
    return view('pages.home')->withFood($foods);
}
```

**and heres Foods.show controller function**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $foods = Food::Find($id);
    return view('foods.show')->withFood($foods);
}
```

please what am i doing wrong

Comment: you should make it global. place this code in your service provider View::share('data', [1, 2, 3]);

Comment: Change `->withFood($foods);` to `->with('foods', $foods);`

Comment: wnhich code? and why do i have to make it global

Comment: @sta let me try your option

Comment: if you wanted the variable to be `foods` it would be `withFoods` not `withFood`

Comment: The accurate answer provided by @lagbox it should be `withFoods` not `withFood`

Comment: Btw, delete this line `$foods = Food::all();` from `LoadHome()`,  no need to call that.

Comment: thanks everyone for their help, fixed it already

the problem was withFoods not withFood

public function show($id)
    {
        $foods = Food::Find($id);
        return view('foods.show')->withFoods($foods);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing data from your controller to the view using this something like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $foods = Food::Find($id);
    return view('foods.show')->with('foods', $foods);
}
```

or, if you're passing multiple variables to the view:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $foods = Food::Find($id);
    $something = "else";
    return view('foods.show', compact('foods', 'something'));
}
```

Your view doesn't know what `$foods` is at that point, so it's always good practice to check that foods is set before the loop:

```
@if (isset($foods) && $foods->count() > 0)
    @foreach($foods as $food)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

See the [official Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views) docs for more information.

Comment: yes i have , thats exactly how i passed my data into my view

Comment: thanks everyone for their help, fixed it already

the problem was withFoods not withFood

public function show($id)
    {
        $foods = Food::Find($id);
        return view('foods.show')->withFoods($foods);
    }

thanks again\

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable to be named `foods` in the view then you would need to use `withFoods` not `withFood`:

```
return view(...)->withFoods($foods);
```

As mentioned in the other answers, there are other ways to pass data to the views as well.

Comment: thanks everyone for their help, fixed it already

the problem was withFoods not withFood

public function show($id)
    {
        $foods = Food::Find($id);
        return view('foods.show')->withFoods($foods);
    }

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is no data being passed to a view.

This is how you pass data to a view:

```
public function LoadHome()
{          
    $foods = Food::orderBy('created_at','desc')->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(12)
        ->get();
    return view('pages.home', ['foods' => $foods])
}
```

If you always want to have $foods in main.blade.php you should place this in a service provider

```
View::share('foods', Food::orderBy('created_at','desc')->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(12)
        ->get());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: View::share('foods', Food::orderBy('created_at','desc')->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(12)
        ->get());         you mean i should add this to my AppSerivceProvider.php file right? @frogeyedman

Comment: and i tried this.   public function LoadHome()
{          
    $foods = Food::orderBy('created_at','desc')->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(12)
        ->get();
    return view('pages.home', ['foods' => $foods])
} .  it gave the same result.

Comment: thanks everyone for their help, fixed it already

the problem was withFoods not withFood

public function show($id)
    {
        $foods = Food::Find($id);
        return view('foods.show')->withFoods($foods);
    }

thanks again